# Number Guessing game using SimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am new to coding as a whole and I'm trying to use PySimpleGUI to make a simple guessing game. The game shows you a random number between 1 and 12. You guess whether the next random number will be larger or smaller than the first. Once you make a guess, it reveals the second number and checks if you were correct or incorrect.

I have little to no idea how to code the GUI correctly and I probably also don't understand how classes and "self" works in Python.

Here are the snippets I am worried about. I tried to emulate other code, but I probably am very misguided.

```
class GameMenu(Number):
layout = [
        [sg.Text('The first number is:\n'), sg.Text(key = 'suggestion')],
        [sg.Text('Will the next number bet smaller or larger than the first?')],
        [sg.Button('Smaller'), sg.Button('Larger')],
        [sg.Text('The second number is: '), sg.Text(key = 'answer')],
        [sg.AnswerCheck('Check', key='Check')],
        [sg.Button('Run'), sg.Button('Quit')],
    ]
        
self.window = sg.Window('Number Game', layout)
    
while True:
    event, self = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == 'Quit':
        break
    elif event == 'Run':
        main()
    elif event == 'Smaller' or 'Larger':
        self._guess_check(event)

def _guess_check(self, event):
    answer = random.randrange(1, 13)
    self.window['answer'].update(answer)
```

'NUMBER' is its own class where I tried to define the two random numbers, to be filled in in each iteration.

Of course, the end goal is for the game to generate both numbers sequentially, while the user makes their choices, and then lets them try again or quit.

---

---

I'll include the full code below, so you can see everything:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import random

class Number:
    def __init__(self, suggestion, answer):
        self._suggestion = suggestion
        self._answer = answer

    def random_number(self):
        self._suggestion = random.randrange(1, 13)
        self._answer = random.randrange(1, 13)

class GameMenu(Number):
    layout = [
            [sg.Text('The first number is:\n'), sg.Text(key = 'suggestion')],
            [sg.Text('Will the next number bet smaller or larger than the first?')],
            [sg.Button('Smaller'), sg.Button('Larger')],
            [sg.Text('The second number is: '), sg.Text(key = 'answer')],
            [sg.AnswerCheck('Check', key='Check')],
            [sg.Button('Run'), sg.Button('Quit')],
        ]
            
    self.window = sg.Window('Number Game', layout)
        
    while True:
        event, self = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == 'Quit':
            break
        elif event == 'Run':
            main()
        elif event == 'Smaller' or 'Larger':
            self._guess_check(event)

    def _guess_check(self, event):
        answer = random.randrange(1, 13)
        self.window['answer'].update(answer)

def main():
    game_menu = GameMenu()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

window.close()
```

**Edit:**

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import random



'''
class Number:
    def __init__(values, suggestion, answer):
        values._suggestion = suggestion
        values._answer = answer

    def random_number(values):
        values._suggestion = random.randrange(1, 13)
        values._answer = random.randrange(1, 13)
'''

class GameMenu():
    def __init__(self):
        layout = [
            [sg.Button('Start'), sg.Button('Quit')]
        ]

        self.window = sg.window('Number Game', layout)
        
    def play(values):
        layout = [
            [sg.Text('The first number is:\n'), sg.Text(key = 'suggestion')],
            [sg.Text('Will the next number bet smaller or larger than the first?')],
            [sg.Button('Smaller'), sg.Button('Larger')],
            [sg.Text('The second number is: '), sg.Text(key = 'answer')],
            [sg.Text('Check', key='Check')],
            [sg.Button('Start Over'), sg.Button('Quit')],
        ]

        values.window = sg.window('Number Game', layout)
        
    def random_number(values):
        values._suggestion = random.randrange(1, 13)
        values._answer = random.randrange(1, 13)

        while True:
            event, values = window.read()
            print(f'Above outcome ran window.read with event {event} and values :{values}:') #can remove afterwards. this helps me find where stuff goes wrong
            if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == 'Quit':
                break
            elif event == 'Start':
                GameMenu.play()

            elif event == 'Smaller' or 'Larger':
                values._guess_check(event)

    def _guess_check(self, event):
        answer = random.randrange(1, 13)
        self.window['answer'].update(answer)

def main():
    GameMenu

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

window.close()
```

Comment: `I have little to no idea how to code the GUI correctly and I probably also don't understand how classes and "self" works in Python` I suggest you slow down, take a step back, and don't try to do everything all at once. Learn these topics separately and play around with them before trying to use them all at once. It's much easier to learn that way, rather than trying to do everything and then getting stuck and frustrated because you understand none of it. Don't get ahead of yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of code, really a complete application.  To get past bugs, particularly in GUI code, you need to make smaller and smaller programs.  The goal is to add one thing and say "Aha!  That is unexpected!"

One item that might help is adding `enable_events=True` to your `sg.Button()` calls.  Another might be that the line `event, self = window.read()` would be better as `event, values = window.read()` and
followed with `print(f"Just did window.read with event {event} and values :{values}:")`  Hopefully, this will get you a bit further.

Programming does get better. One great habit you could get into is keeping notes, such as what errors you run across.

Keep on programming.  Keep notes.